# add_rewrite_endpoint() and Custom Post Type Archive

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives, rewrite-rules, endpoints

I've got a custom post type. Let's call it `books`. I'm adding a new rewrite endpoint called `pages`.

I want the url `/books/pages/2/` to work but I don't see any rewrite rules generated by WordPress for this. I can manually add the rewrite rules for this specific example, but I'm looking for a way to make this work automatically.

How can I make this work automatically for any given custom post type archives? I'm guessing I'll need to add a function to my plugin to look for all of the custom post types registered for the current site and then loop over that list adding the custom rewrite rules. Any better ideas?

**Update**
This is what I ended up doing:

```
function my_plugin_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $pages_regex = '?([\d\-]+|all)';

    $args = array(
        'has_archive' => true
    );
    $post_types = get_post_types( $args );

    $new_rewrites = array();
    foreach( $post_types as $post_type ) {
        $key = $post_type . '/pages/' . $pages_regex . '/?$';
        $val = 'post_type=' . $post_type . '&pages=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1);

        $new_rewrites[ $key ] = $val;
    }

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rewrites + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_plugin_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: *"I'm guessing I'll need to add a function to my plugin to look for all of the custom post types registered for the current site and then loop over that list adding the custom rewrite rules"* Guessing right. Only recall to flush rewrite rules on plugin activation/deactivation. *"Any better ideas?"* I have other ideas, but to complex for a comment and for an answer too. I can only suggest a look at [this](https://github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/CleverRules)

Comment: @G.M. Well at least I'm not overlooking something more obvious.